# Chrome browser console global variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have small doubt in difference of local variable and global variable in browser console, when i type `var a = 5` and hit enter in chrome browser console it returns undefined but when i type `a = 5` not returning anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with local vs. global variables. It's just that what the console shows you is the result of the statement. `var` statements don't have a result, so you see `undefined`. Assignment statements<sup>1</sup> *do* have a result (the assigned value), so you see that value.

If you did

```
var a = 5;
a
```

...you'd see `undefined` followed by `5`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, it's an *expression statement* containing an *assignment expression*.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding when you write `a=5`, this will create a global variable. So it would be a part of `window` object. Hence you get its value.

When you do `var a = 5`, a new variable(reference) will be created, and then value will be set. Hence, you will get `undefined`.

You can even try following code for testing.

```js
var a = {};
a.b = 5;
```

This will return `5` and not `undefined`.

Comment: I have doubt here, So first new reference variable will create after that it will returns undefined after value will assign to reference variable

Comment: Sort of. So since compiler will have to create a new reference, it will create it and return its value and make *setting value* action as async